# Finding records of emigration/immigration from Germany to South Africa?

Tags: germany, immigration, 1920s, south-africa, bavaria

My paternal grandfather was born in 1900 in Attenhoffen, Germany. He came to South Africa in the 1920s. My quest is to find out how and when? There is a story that he was a seaman who jumped ship in Walvis Bay.

His name was Sebastian Decker born 12 Jan 1900, parents Leonhard and Anna nee Schmeid. Born in Attenhoffen, Bavaria. This according to an archive copy of his birth certificate. I have looked on geni and ancestry. I think the problem is that according to family stories he was a seaman not a paying passenger who jumped ship in Namibia.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH Brendan! This is a great question but it would be even better if you could include a few more details of sources you have already tried searching, for example have you looked at the [Hamberg Passenger Lists](http://search.ancestry.com/search/db.aspx?dbid=1068) on Ancestry.com? You can make changes to your question by using the [edit] button at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Do you mean Attenhofen in Bavaria (a long way from the sea-coast)?

Comment: You do not need to include your grandfather's name but if you wish to that would be fine, because he was born more than 100 years ago, and could help potential answerers explore a few options by having a specific example of someone to look for in the relevant record sets.

Comment: his name was Sebastian Decker born 12 Jan 1900, parents Leonhard and Anna nee Schmeid. Born in Attenhoffen, Bavaria. This according to an archive copy of his birth certificate. I have looked on geni and ancestry. I think the problem is that according to family stories he was a seaman not a paying passenger who jumped ship in Namibia.

Comment: I moved your new information into the question body because potential answerers may not always read the comments.  There is an [edit] button beneath it that lets you revise or add detail to your question at any time.